# How do I take a user input list, run it through random counter, then output results

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry in advance, I'm fairly new to coding, and this maybe something rather simple. I want to make a quick program that allows a user to input items, do say 1000 permutations of randomly picking an item from the list, then outputting the number of times each item was picked in descending order. I have some code that does some what of what I want, using a predefined list. But I am not sure how to convert it to using a user input list. Here is the code:

```
ThingsToDo = ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Bananas', 'Watermelons', 'Grapes']

results = random.choices(ThingsToDo, k=1000)

countApples = results.count('Apples')
countOranges = results.count('Oranges')
countBananas = results.count('Bananas')
countWatermelons = results.count('Watermelons')
countGrapes = results.count('Grapes')

print('Apples:', countApples)
print('Oranges:', countOranges)
print('Bananas:', countBananas)
print('Watermelons:', countWatermelons)
print('Grapes:', countGrapes)
```

Now while this somewhat accomplishes what I want, what I would like to happen is have a user input an undefined amount of items into a list. Then run a user defined amount of times and output the results.... Hopefully this makes sense. I have how to ask the user for list inputs here:

```
print('Please enter values for the list, one value per line')
print('Enter "done" (without the quotes) to end the list')

list_of_inputs = []
while True:
    s = input('value: ')
    if s == 'done':
        break
    list_of_inputs.append(s)

print('Here is the list:')
print(list_of_inputs)
```

I am just not sure how to take the user's list and run in through the above code... Sure hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use a bunch of unrelated variables, but rather a `dict`. In this case, you can even use a [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which is a `dict` subclass, to do the counting for you:

```
import random
from collections import Counter

list_of_inputs = ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Bananas', 'Watermelons', 'Grapes']

results = random.choices(list_of_inputs, k=1000)

counts = Counter(results)
# Counter({'Watermelons': 218, 'Bananas': 211, 'Oranges': 211, 'Grapes': 187, 'Apples': 173})

for item, count in counts.items():
    print(f'{item}: {count}')
```

Sample output:

```
Bananas: 210
Oranges: 201
Grapes: 198
Apples: 208
Watermelons: 183
```

Or, if you want them sorted by decreasing count, using the Counter's `most_common` method:

```
for item, count in counts.most_common():
    print(f'{item}: {count}')
```

Or sorted by item name, by iterating on the sorted keys of `counts`:

```
for item in sorted(counts):
    print(f'{item}: {counts[item]}')
```